# Apple Mach-0 linker warning

Tags: ios, xcode, 64-bit, warnings

I'm fairly new to ios programming. I've got an app that I think is almost ready for the appstore. However, I have one remaining warning and I'm not sure how to track down where the problem lies.

Here's the warning:
(null): Ignoring file /Users/maclehose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/epidemiologyCalculator-esumevitgvkrmsfrmqeerqjyjfoh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/epidemiologyCalculator.app/epidemiologyCalculator, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/maclehose/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/epidemiologyCalculator-esumevitgvkrmsfrmqeerqjyjfoh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/epidemiologyCalculator.app/epidemiologyCalculator (2 slices)

Can anyone give me any specific advice on how to track down the source of the warning?

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

Go to targets and then Build Settings. Then turn the architectures to (armv7, armv7s). Like this you can silence the warning. [image: Screenshot]

But then when you change it like this, it means that your app doesn't gets compiled for the 64-Bit architecture (iPhone 5S uses it).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I've already got (armv7, armv7s) set as the architecture. I'm using corePlot and got a ton of errors with the 64 bit architecture. so i'm still getting the warning even with this change. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 64-bit setting, if performance is not an issue. However if you really need it, you'll need to compile and build CorePlot library from source by adding it as a dependent project inside your app.

Comment: Thanks for your help as well. I changed the setting in coreplot to 64bit, recompiled and added the new build to my project. i then switched the architecture in my own project to (including 64-bit).  i still get exactly the same error as above. so, i assume this has nothing to do with coreplot. but how do i figure out where the problem is? the app seems to work fine in the simulators....maybe this isn't worth tracking down?

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project before you rebuild the app? Also have you checked that valid architectures under build settings include arm64? When you added the new build to your project, did you check also the build phases under project settings? Try re-adding the newly build 64-bit framework. You can check whether it's build for arm64 via Terminal: `lipo -info libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a`